# Install ROS-Melodic on Ubuntu 18 (Bionic): unmet dependencies / Unable to locate package

Tags: ros-melodic, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To install ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic), I am following the instructions given [here](https://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu).

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-melodic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-melodic-perception but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-melodic-simulators but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-melodic-urdf-sim-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Dependencies of `ros-melodic-simulators` & `ros-melodic-urdf-sim-tutorial` can be taken care of by installing  gazebo from  [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install#InstallGazebousingUbuntupackages).

Attempt to install `ros-melodic-perception` using `apt` results in,

```
ros-melodic-perception : Depends: ros-melodic-perception-pcl but it is not going to be installed
```

Consequently, attempt to install `ros-melodic-perception-pcl` results in,

```
ros-melodic-perception-pcl : Depends: ros-melodic-pcl-conversions but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-melodic-pcl-ros but it is not going to be installed
```

However, neither `ros-melodic-pcl-conversions` could be found,

```
$ sudo apt install ros-melodic-perception-pcl-conversions
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-perception-pcl-conversions
```

nor `ros-melodic-pcl-ros`.

```
$ sudo apt install ros-melodic-perception-pcl-ros
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-perception-pcl-ros
```

---

As mentioned in the installation instructions, Ubuntu repositories have been configured to download from "main", "restricted," "universe," and "multiverse".

[image: image description]

What is going wrong in there?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306742/install-ros-melodic-on-ubuntu-18-(bionic):-unmet-dependencies-/-unable-to-locate-package/) by [Sumit Dey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27553/sumit-dey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2018-10-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are not the package names, which explains why apt can't find them:

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-perception-pcl-ros
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-perception-pcl-conversions
```

This *should* work without any additional fiddling:

```
apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

So it's likely your system install is borked in some way. Try using aptitude instead of apt-get, which is much more clever about telling you what's wrong and how to fix it.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2018-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sumit Dey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27553/sumit-dey/) on 2018-10-25**:
aptitude did the job. Thanks.
Problem: vtk-7 was installed.. where as melodic needs vtk-6.

**Comment by [jurban1997](https://answers.ros.org/users/38461/jurban1997/) on 2018-11-10**:
Failed for me.  Does anyone QA these instructions?